# Return statement in Java methods

Tags: java, methods, return

I am beginner in Java i am learning about Java methods in my tutorial there is this code:

```
public class JavaLessonSix {

    static double myPI = 3.14159;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        addThem(1, 2);
    }

    public static int addThem(int a,int b){

    int c = a + b;

    System.out.println(c);

    return c;
    }
}
```

I did not really understood what return statement means. Could you please describe to me what the return statement means in Java..?

Comment: Even better: use [`Math.PI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI)

Comment: Please read [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 7):

`return` does what it names suggests. It *returns* the value of c. so if you have this

```
int result = addThem(1, 2);
```

`result` will equal 3, so you can then print it in main.

Comment: Outside of programming, "return" often suggests that something is giving/sending/etc. the same thing it was given.  I can return a gift to you, but if you give me a loaf of bread and some fillings, it's a bit odd to say that I _returned_ a sandwich to you.  That said, +1 for giving an example where the return value of a method call is used.  In the OPs code, there was no use of the return value, so (from OP's perspective) `addThem` could have as well been a `void` method.

Answer (score 4):

A `statement` is a single instruction, roughly every line of code that does something is a statement.

A `return statement` is one like `return c`.

Return statements stop the execution of a method and return the final value (or nothing in case of `void` methods).

Execution continues at the place that called the method. The value you returned is used in place of the method call and calulation can continue.

Answer (score 1):

A Java method is a collection of statements that are grouped together to perform an operation.So when you call any method to complete some task,so it will give you the result of the method.In below code :

```
public static int addThem(int a,int b){

    int c = a + b;

    System.out.println(c);

    return c;   ----->>> Returning result (int)
    }
```

You are having method `addThem` whose task is to add the two number but in what data type it will return the result..

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement does the following:

- Ceases method execution immediately
- Provides the output of the method to the caller. If you're a math-y sort, if *x* is the input to a function and *f(x)* is the output, then the `return` value is the analogue to `f(x)`.

Consider this method:

```
public boolean isEven(int number) {
  return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

The caller might say

```
if (isEven(givenNumber)) {
 //Do stuff
}
```

So if *x* is `givenNumber` and *f* is `isEven`, *f(x)* is `isEven(givenNumber)`. The `return` statement specifies just what that answer is.

You can also think of it this way. Since `isEven(4)` returns `true`

I can replace this

if (<strike>isEven(givenNumber)</strike>)

with this

```
if (true)
```

when `givenNumber` = 4 because `true` is what got returned.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what a method is: a method is a modular structure consisting of integrated units arranged in a logical order to form a complete unit.

Meaning when a method is called it does 'something'. So, you want to know whether that 'something' is right, or not!

When you add a return type in your method prototype, and in your method body you specify the actual variable to return, this allows you to pass back such value generated internally.